# Can you check whether your OS and java runtime are 32-bit or 64-bit from within your program?

Tags: java

I was told there is a System Environment Property File i could check, however, it hasn't yielded any definite results so far.

Basically I need to see what version of the OS and Java i'm running so I can copy the correct DLLs to the run directory. As always, a better solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check JRE version checkin os.arch property of System class

http://mark.koli.ch/2009/10/javas-osarch-system-property-is-the-bitness-of-the-jre-not-the-operating-system.html

Comment: Is there a way to check the OS itself? Or should I just work around this.

Answer (score 0):

JNLP - Java Web Start - allows for specifying DLL's and shared libraries per architecture.  This allows you to do centralized distribution with a local icon for the users to click.